# AngularJS caches $http.post responce

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I've been fiddling with AngularJS for a while now and I came across a problem.

Every time a make a change to an element (create/delete/update) the request is sent and saved to the database.
The problem is that my changes are not loaded the next time I refresh the page - old data is sent as a response from the server without the changes I've made.

I'm using .NET MVC for the backend and AngularJS on the front-end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

Edit:

I've a reason to believe that .net is the problem - After I rebuild the whole solution it loads the changes.

Comment: Check the response headers for cache expiry.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, conceptually correct way is to disable caching on server side. The reason is that you have custom behavior and you want to load "fresh" data after every postback. Whenever you call the same method via another client or access the url directly, you should see up-to-date data. Here is the sample excerpt how to disable caching:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=0, VaryByParam="*")]
public JsonResult Details()
{
    //snip snip
    return Json(theResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$http.post({
    url: "example.cpm",
    cache: false      //This comes from jQuery
    //etc..
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Caching is at times at level of browser and you can not force browser to not cache from javascript. This is not specifically Angular issue.

If its caching of some html/js file what you can probably do is append timestamp to url so every time your url is new and no caching is done.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the JavaScript that's cached - I'm recording the output with the Chrome developer tools from the responses to my requests (Network tab) and it doesn't return the changes from the back-end.

Comment: Then its surely browser caching that's culprit...you can disable that, one way could be adding timestamp to url as I mentioned.

Comment: How can it be that the JS is cached when the response I get from the back-end doesn't contain the changes? The js code simply doesn't recognize the changes (since they are not returned) and works as it should. It can not be browser caching since its disabled always from the Dev tools.

Comment: Do you see a network request going to server, if you are using Dev Tools you can see what the server returned...if server is not returning any changes, than  can it be JS caching issue.

Comment: Yeah i see the request and response - the request parameters are OK but the data returned from server for those parameters doesn't contain the changes.. Are you saying the response is cached?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see something like this in browser, it means that browser is caching the response and the response you are getting is not coming from server.

[image]

This caching is not at level of javascript or rather angular but browser caching. There are various ways to make sure that browser does not servers response from cache.

Comment: No there is no (from cache) right next to the status code